# Plugin generated taxonomies' permalinks with custom placeholders

Tags: plugins, custom-taxonomy, permalinks, url-rewriting

I have a problem with permalinks for custom taxonomies generated with Types http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/types/, a plugin for creating taxonomies, custom posts and custom fields.

The problem is that once i set up my taxonomy i'm not able to configure the permalinks.

The options for my taxonomies are:
Plural name: Volumes
Singular name: Volume
Slug: volume
Rewrite: yes

In the permalinks i choose custom and set: `/%volume%/%postname%/`

But then the posts url, instead of showing the actual taxonomy slug, it shows the permalink code, link eg this: `http://www.zonasismica.sism.org/%issues%/editoriale/`

The post name is replaced, but the taxonomy not. Of course the link doesn't work...

I really cannot understand what is going wrong here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it's not something can be done without digging into the code.

However i found a plugin the fits my needs pretty well: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/taxonomic-seo-permalinks/

with this you can just set /%your-taxonomy%/%postname%/ in the permalinks settings page and your done!